# Rtp H264 non-idr slice relate for idr-slice

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, rtp

According to [RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984) RFC, When sniffing non-idr slice, how to know which idr slice it relate for?

I didn't find any area in the packet that configure that, or it just relates to the idr slice that was before according to sequence number>

Answer (score 0):

The relationship of non-IDR slices and IDR slice is part of the H.264 code stream and is probably not replicated in RTP. For information about H.264 see: https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-201906-I/en.
This is a good introductory article about H.264 picture management: https://www.vcodex.com/h264avc-picture-management/